# Is there a way to make it shorter, maybe recursiv? Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, recursion

i wanted to ask if there is a way to make the following code  shorter.
I think that there should be a way to do it recursiv but I am not sure about it as recursiv is not my strongest side :/ 
Later at each of the computed states there should something happen but this is just a monster :/

```
 public void VertexState() { // Try to find the next vertex state to test
    int end = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int place;
    int up = 1;
    int zaehler = 1;

    try {
        for (int u = 0; u < 4; u++) {
            for (int t = 0; t < 4; t++) {
                for (int s = 0; s < 4; s++) {
                    for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
                        for (int q = 0; q < 4; q++) {
                            for (int p = 0; p < 4; p++) {
                                for (int o = 0; o < 4; o++) {
                                    for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
                                        for (int m = 0; m < 4; m++) {
                                            for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++) {
                                                for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                                                    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                                                        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                                                            for (int h = 0; h < 4; h++) {
                                                                for (int g = 0; g < 4; g++) {

                                                                    for (int f = 0; f < 4; f++) {
                                                                        for (int e = 0; e < 4; e++) {
                                                                            for (int d = 0; d < 4; d++) {
                                                                                for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
                                                                                    for (int b = 0; b < 4; b++) {
                                                                                        for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
                                                                                            work[0][findPlace()].countUp();
                                                                                            work[findPlace()][0].countUp();


                                                                                        }
                                                                                        work[0][findNextPlace(1)].countUp();
                                                                                        work[findNextPlace(1)][0].countUp();

                                                                                    }
                                                                                    work[0][findNextPlace(2)].countUp();
                                                                                    work[findNextPlace(2)][0].countUp();

                                                                                }
                                                                                work[0][findNextPlace(3)].countUp();
                                                                                work[findNextPlace(3)][0].countUp();

                                                                            }
                                                                            work[0][findNextPlace(4)].countUp();
                                                                            work[findNextPlace(4)][0].countUp();
                                                                        }
                                                                        work[0][findNextPlace(5)].countUp();
                                                                        work[findNextPlace(5)][0].countUp();
                                                                    }
                                                                    work[0][findNextPlace(6)].countUp();
                                                                    work[findNextPlace(6)][0].countUp();
                                                                }
                                                                work[0][findNextPlace(7)].countUp();
                                                                work[findNextPlace(7)][0].countUp();
                                                            }
                                                            work[0][findNextPlace(8)].countUp();
                                                            work[findNextPlace(8)][0].countUp();
                                                        }
                                                        work[0][findNextPlace(9)].countUp();
                                                        work[findNextPlace(9)][0].countUp();
                                                    }
                                                    work[0][findNextPlace(10)].countUp();
                                                    work[findNextPlace(10)][0].countUp();
                                                }
                                                work[0][findNextPlace(11)].countUp();
                                                work[findNextPlace(11)][0].countUp();
                                            }
                                            work[0][findNextPlace(12)].countUp();
                                            work[findNextPlace(12)][0].countUp();
                                        }
                                        work[0][findNextPlace(13)].countUp();
                                        work[findNextPlace(13)][0].countUp();
                                    }
                                    work[0][findNextPlace(14)].countUp();
                                    work[findNextPlace(14)][0].countUp();
                                }
                                work[0][findNextPlace(15)].countUp();
                                work[findNextPlace(15)][0].countUp();

                                work[0][findNextPlace(16)].countUp();
                                work[findNextPlace(16)][0].countUp();
                            }
                            work[0][findNextPlace(17)].countUp();
                            work[findNextPlace(17)][0].countUp();
                        }
                        work[0][findNextPlace(18)].countUp();
                        work[findNextPlace(18)][0].countUp();
                    }
                    work[0][findNextPlace(19)].countUp();
                    work[findNextPlace(19)][0].countUp();
                }
                work[0][findNextPlace(20)].countUp();
                work[findNextPlace(20)][0].countUp();
            }
            work[0][findNextPlace(21)].countUp();
            work[findNextPlace(21)][0].countUp();


        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("over and out");
    }

}


public int findPlace() {
    int place = work.length;
    for (place = work.length - 1; place >= 0; place--) {
        if (work[0][place] != null) {
            return place;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I really hope you can help me :)
Thank you very much

Comment: may have been asked here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: And what is it suppose to do ? You have loop but don't use the values ...

Comment: what the heck are you trying to do? can you explain it in words?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle:  No, this probably shouldn't be asked at Code Review.

Comment: After every count up there will be another methode in it, which makes something with the work-array

(The array describes a graph)

Comment: I'm a bit lost with this loop; despite its size and the fact that it's *so* deep, you don't actually use any of the variables.

Comment: What is the need ? I see the findNextPlace incrementing (use ONE for loop maybe). Why 4 time on each ?

Comment: With every step i change the work-array.
And i should compute a special state of all vertexes. A vertex can have the values 0-3 (thats why i count them up 4 times everytime). And i need every possible combination of these values and then see if its the goal state

Comment: The inner code of this loop will run 4^21 times. That is over 4 trillion times. That is going to take a lot of time!

Comment: @ValentinO. but she never uses the loop variables there...

Comment: @marstran yay i know but i dont know any better way to do it  :/ and i have to do the same with the 21*21 edges... :/

Comment: @rosenkat if you describe what you want to achieve we may suggest you better algorithm. But please do it in separate question.

Comment: Even with probably much better code in the answers I still feel like this generates a structure of some sort that is elementary enough to be calculatable or even simpler than the recursive version, however it's not enough code in your question to actualy test what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the pattern.

- You iterate from `0` to `3`
- Then do `something`
- then invoke `work[0][findNextPlace(21)].countUp();` and `work[findNextPlace(21)][0].countUp();`

`something` is just you pattern but with different number passed to `findNextPlace`.

You do this until you pass `0` to `findNextPlace`.

Let's rewrite your code:

```
 void something(int parameter) {
     if(parameter < 0) {
         for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
             work[0][findPlace(parameter)].countUp();
             work[findPlace(parameter)][0].countUp();
         }
     } else {
         for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
             something(parameter - 1);
             work[0][findNextPlace(parameter)].countUp();
             work[findNextPlace(parameter)][0].countUp();
         }
     }
 }
```

Then you just replace whole your `for` pyramid with `something(21)`;

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to ask why you need this but I think this would be the recursive form:

```
    void recursiveImpl(int iterator)
    {
        iterator++;
        if (iterator == 1)
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++)
            {
                recursiveImpl(iterator);

                work[0][findPlace()].countUp();
                work[findPlace()][0].countUp();                   
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++)
            {
                if (iterator < 22)
                {
                    recursiveImpl(iterator);
                }
                work[0][findNextPlace(iterator)].countUp();
                work[findNextPlace(iterator)][0].countUp();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `recursiveImpl` should be invoked inside loop.

Comment: @talex fixed it, I think, care to check it out?

Comment: Original code invoke inner loops before it do actual work. you should move `recursiveImpl` few more line up :)

Comment: Is better now, but look at your branches now. They almost same (if you keep in mind that `1<22` they occur to be identical)

Comment: @talex checkout OPs innermost for loop, he calls a different method there: On is "findPlace()" the other is "findNextplace("number")"

Comment: Got it. I'm not watchful enough.